# React web workers are loading from a strange function

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app, web-worker

I've spent possible the worst day of my life trying to get web workers run inside a create react app.

If I just import

```
import VoiceWorker from './voice.worker.js'
```

And

```
  voiceWorker = new Worker(VoiceWorker)
  voiceWorker.postMessage({command:'start'})
```

It works fine locally but not on the server where it can't find the worker file.

So I've followed various instructions, I can't use the inline blob method because the webworker has dependencies.

I updated React-Scripts to 2.0.5 because somewhere I read that it had support for webworkers, but it doesn't seem to.

I've been using the worker-loader library, used `react-app-rewired`

With the config-overrides below

```
const path = require('path')
const WorkerPlugin = require('worker-plugin')

module.exports = function override(config, env) {
  config.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.worker\.js$/,
    use: { loader: 'worker-loader' },
  })

  config.plugins.push(new WorkerPlugin())
  config.output.globalObject= `this`

  return config
}
```

And `import VoiceWorker from 'worker-loader!./voice.worker.js'`

This is now trying to load the worker from the below URL and fails:
[https://localhost:3000/course/function()%20%7B%20%20return%20new%20Worker(**webpack_require**.p%20+%20%220306a1085789e37891cf.worker.js%22);%7D](https://localhost:3000/course/function()%20%7B%20%20return%20new%20Worker(__webpack_require__.p%20+%20%220306a1085789e37891cf.worker.js%22);%7D)

I've tried the worker plugin as above and that doesn't do anything.

I got it loading before and 'window' was undefined but that line config.output.globalObject= `this`fixed that.

Please can someone tell me a way to get workers loading in React! ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with https://github.com/developit/workerize-loader which seems to be more mature.

react-app-rewired with `config.output.globalObject= self` helps with the 'window is undefined' problem.